# Error: Database schema comparison using schema project with Azure database

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-sql-database, database-schema

I'm using database project for maintaining database schemas. Schema comparison works perfectly with local databases. But when I connect to Azure database and compare with the schema project, it throws following error.

> Unexpected exception caught during population of target model: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: catalogStamp

I have tried cleaning up all the saved connections via `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\SSDT\ConnectionMruList`

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try installing Visual Studio 2017 on another machine or a virtual machine. You may find it has been fixed on Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. It works on 2017

Comment: I am glad to know Aruna. This may be a good reason to upgrade.

Comment: Exactly. Already started the conversion. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing Visual Studio 2017 on another machine or a virtual machine. It has been fixed on Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 2):

Good to know that it's been corrected in VS2017 but for anyone on earlier versions of VS, who want to know the cause is, it happens due to a compatibility mode mismatch with the database. I saw this after Microsoft upgraded the default database compatibility level on Azure last year (see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/default-compatibility-level-140-for-azure-sql-databases/)

If you are remaining on an older version of Visual Studio then you can change the compatibility level using:

```
ALTER DATABASE [Database_Name] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 120
```

But you should first make **sure that any differences between compatibility levels will not cause you a problem**, see; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level

You can check the current compatibility level your databases are on with

```
SELECT name, compatibility_level FROM sys.databases
```

Comment: This thread is a godsend and this answer is perfect. Deployment with VS 2015 database to Azure SQL gives me the error. Azure SQL was created at compatability_level 150. I changed it to compatability_level 120. Now VS2015 schema comparison and deployment works!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ALTER DATABASE [Database_Name] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 120
```